Troubleshooting Inconsistent Work Item Retrieval in Azure DevOps Release API
I have an Azure DevOps API for fetching the releases between the start date and the end date
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/releases?minCreatedTime=${startDate}&maxCreatedTime=${endDate}&api-version=6.0,
startDate : 2024-05-27,
endDate   : 2024-07-11
Basically, when I run this API it gives the releases which contain the release id
so I have passed the release id to another API to fetch the workitems
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/release/releases/${releaseId}/workitems?api-version=7.1
When I run this API, the work items associated with each release ID are incorrect. On 2024-07-15, the API returned 440 work items, which is accurate. However, when I ran the same API on 2024-07-16, it only returned 215 work items. I am not receiving the same work items; the API is showing fewer work items.
could anyone help me out from this case
When I run this API, the work items associated with each release ID are incorrect. On 2024-07-15, the API returned 440 work items, which is accurate. However, when I ran the same API on 2024-07-16, it only returned 215 work items. I am not receiving the same work items; the API is showing fewer work items.
I am expecting the resolution such that it should contains all the workitems in the release


When I run this API, the work items associated with each release ID are incorrect. On 2024-07-15, the API returned 440 work items, which is accurate. However, when I ran the same API on 2024-07-16, it only returned 215 work items. I am not receiving the same work items; the API is showing fewer work items.

The two rest api could have different output if you run one day after.
For 1st rest api, when you get all releases in duration, it could happen that some releases were deleted(manually or by retained policy) in the day, the rest api won't list the deleted releases. Hence it could get less release id to 2nd rest api.
Removed a release and get different release number for same rest api on my side:

Same for 2nd rest api, if some associated work items were deleted, when you run again, it will be not listed in the rest api.
Deleted the associated work item, it won't be listed again on my side.


I am expecting the resolution such that it should contains all the workitems in the release

Actually you are doing in the correct way, but need to make sure there's no change on the release number and no work items deleted, to make sure you have same output between two runs. You can output the release id and work item id for confirmation.

Thank you for the reply
Just now I found that the resolution is :
In the Azure DevOps pipeline, we have the release retention period so as soon as the retention period expires the releases that are there in the release pipeline will be deleted
so we need to increase the release retention period

Glad to know it helps! as i mentioned above, the release could be deleted by the retention policy.  the rest api won't list the deleted releases. Happy day!

Thank you for the reply
Just now I found that the resolution is :
In the Azure DevOps pipeline, we have the release retention period so as soon as the retention period expires the releases that are there in the release pipeline will be deleted
so we need to increase the release retention period
